# Is there an easy way to find out what connection string parameters an ODBC driver requires using .Net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, odbc

I'm building a program which will allow a user to easily configure an ODBC data source for an application. I don't want to rely on the ODBC driver utility that came with Windows.

Different ODBC drivers require different connection string parameters, e.g. SQL Server accepts "Initial Catalog=", but MS Jet requires "DBQ" to point it to its file. Excel wants "Excel File=".

Using only VB.Net (ideally) or C#.Net (less ideally), is there a relatively easy way I can interrogate the ODBC driver the user has chosen to determine what parameters it requires? Obviously, I could code for the 3 samples I've given, but then someone's going to throw a SalesForce.com driver at me, or a CSV file driver... or some yet-to-be-invented driver. I'd like my code to try to cope at least.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but have you considered looking into as many of these drivers as possible and trying to generalise?

Comment: That will be my current approach; I can add a simple listbox type thing which will take additional parameters; I'd hoped to be a bit cleverer than that is all... But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'll have a look later, but perhaps try to find examples of others doing similar things, or look for documentation - maybe there's a way to find out what string a driver requires from the driver itself, so that you can generate them as needed.

Comment: I found some documentation for C++ programmers.... unfortunately, C++ and I never got on :(